# Django - TypeError while getting args in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

**Note: Solved, solution at the end.**

I'm trying to pass a request value to a form I have to filter a field in a form, but it keeps returning TypeError, and I think the code is ok.

views.py:

```
class AddProposalSet(FormView):

    """
    Create a new prpoposal set, it can be related to a debate or be in free mode,
    which is not linked to anything. If it's linked to a debate, people can
    make their proposals related to the debate notes.

    .. versionadded: 0.1.5

    :rtype: Form object
    :context: form, get_place
    """
    #form_class = ProposalSetForm
    template_name = 'proposals/proposalset_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        space = self.kwargs['space_url']
        return reverse(urln_space.SPACE_INDEX, kwargs={'space_url':space})

    def get_form_class(self):
        """
        The reason for overriding "form_class" is that we pass here the
        request to the form, that way we can filter the debates based on the
        current space.
        """
        return ProposalSetForm(self.kwargs['space_url'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.space = get_object_or_404(Space, url=self.kwargs['space_url'])
        form_uncommited = form.save(commit=False)
        form_uncommited.space = self.space
        form_uncommited.author = self.request.user
        form_uncommited.save()
        return super(AddProposalSet, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddProposalSet, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.space = get_object_or_404(Space, url=self.kwargs['space_url'])
        context['get_place'] = self.space
        return context

    @method_decorator(permission_required('proposals.add_proposalset'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddProposalSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class ProposalSetForm(ModelForm):

    """
    ProposalSetForm is a basic form autogenerated form from ProposalSet model.
    Returns an empty form to create a new proposal set.

    :rtype: HTML Form

    .. versionadded:: 0.1.5b
    """
    class Meta:
        model = ProposalSet

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProposalSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        get_place = get_object_or_404(Space, url=args[0])
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['debate'].queryset = Debate.objects.filter(end_date__lte=datetime.date.today(), space=get_place)
```

The error:

```
TypeError at /en-gb/spaces/test/proposal/add/set/
'ProposalSetForm' object is not callable
```

I'm not able to find what can be happening, am I missing something?

**SOLUTION:**

views.py

```
class AddProposalSet(FormView):

    """
    Create a new prpoposal set, it can be related to a debate or be in free mode,
    which is not linked to anything. If it's linked to a debate, people can
    make their proposals related to the debate notes.

    .. versionadded: 0.1.5

    :rtype: Form object
    :context: form, get_place
    """
    form_class = ProposalSetForm
    template_name = 'proposals/proposalset_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        space = self.kwargs['space_url']
        return reverse(urln_space.SPACE_INDEX, kwargs={'space_url':space})

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(AddProposalSet, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        kwargs['initial']['space'] = self.kwargs['space_url']
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.space = get_object_or_404(Space, url=self.kwargs['space_url'])
        form_uncommited = form.save(commit=False)
        form_uncommited.space = self.space
        form_uncommited.author = self.request.user
        form_uncommited.save()
        return super(AddProposalSet, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddProposalSet, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.space = get_object_or_404(Space, url=self.kwargs['space_url'])
        context['get_place'] = self.space
        return context

    @method_decorator(permission_required('proposals.add_proposalset'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddProposalSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class ProposalSetForm(ModelForm):

    """
    ProposalSetForm is a basic form autogenerated form from ProposalSet model.
    Returns an empty form to create a new proposal set.

    :rtype: HTML Form

    .. versionadded:: 0.1.5b
    """
    class Meta:
        model = ProposalSet

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProposalSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        get_place = get_object_or_404(Space, url=kwargs['initial']['space'])
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['debate'].queryset = Debate.objects.filter(end_date__lte=datetime.date.today(), space=get_place)
            print self.fields['debate']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_form_class()` method, should return the class not object/instance of the form class. So your method can be updated to

```
def get_form_class(self):
    return ProposalSetForm
```

However, I'm not sure how will this pass parameters that you need to `__init__()` of the class.

May be you can define `get_form()` rather than `get_form_class()` and return appropriate form instance.

Comment: Then, is there any way to pass a request value to the form? I've been searching but all the docs about sending requests to the form are from the old function based views. :)

Comment: @OscarCarballal, I think you can make use of `get_form_kwargs()` method also.

Comment: I think you have to pass the value through `get` methods or `get_context_data`

Comment: @OtskimanotSqilal, `get_context_data` is for rendering template, so not sure how it can be used here.

Comment: Rohan you were right! It's pretty easy to do with get_form_kwargs(), no wonder why I didn't see it before. I'm marking your answer as the good one and updating my question with the final code.

Answer (score 0):

looks like ProposalSetForm is being called as a function in one of your templates

Comment: Yeah, as Rohan said that's the problem. I thought I could pass the request value there, but apparently I'm doing it wrong.